# Convert pairs of tuples into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples as such:

```
[('thorough', True), ('bliss', True), ('earnest', True)]
```

How can I convert them into dictionary?

**Desired Output**

```
({'thorough':True, 'bliss': True, 'earnest':True})
```

I've tried to use dict() but it cannot output the correct answer.

Comment: Why doesn't `dict()`​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ work? What does `dict()` give you? Have you tried `dict([('thorough', True), ('bliss', True), ('earnest', True)]) == ({'thoroug
h':True, 'bliss': True, 'earnest':True})` to check the output is correct or not?

Comment: How did you use `dict()`, and how did it fail?

Comment: it is one of the arguments to the [`dict` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), a interable of (key,value) tuples.

Comment: Your desired output is a tuple of a dictionary?

Comment: if you want it to be in order then use `OrderedDict(d)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict([('thorough', True), ('bliss', True), ('earnest', True)])
```